# Generate Code like the NetBeans GUI Builder (Java)

Tags: java, code-generation

I am currently working on a project of making a GUI-Builder. I can move some graphical Objects onto a canvas, and set properties for every one. Then I want to generate Code, so that a JFrame will contain all of those Objects. But I am currently stuck at that point. I want to make it farely universal and want to make my GUI-Builder use the JavaBeans technology, so that anyone can create an own Component and my program can use it. But here is the problem: If I have a JTable for instance, and the user set a Table like this: 
A B C D 
E F G H 
I  J  K L

From the custom editor for the TableModel I would get a DefaultTableModel built up like that. But how can I then generate code that looks like the following?

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
        {"E", "F", "G", "H"},
        {"I", "J", "K", "L"},
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
));
```

I could generate Code for that property, but how can I make I'm universal, so that it will work for every property?
I didn't find anything on the Internet, I already read the JavaBeans [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/TOC.html) Trail, but I didn't find anything. As far as I see they talk about writing a bean, not the part of the IDE or GUI-Builder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I would suggest you read about [bean binding](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html) to get some ideas about how to sync a JavaBean state to a GUI form. There is also the GWT [UI Editor](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) framework, which is a very nice example.

Comment: @Boris the Spider Thanks for your help. I updated the question and hope I expressed myself clearer now.

Comment: **You cannot make it universal** (I think) so that it works for every custom component that may come. Or what do you mean exactly? Anyway you have to provide the algorithm to generate the code yourself for the components you support yourself or require it from any custom component.

Comment: @Trioarion But doesn't NetBeans do it universally? Anyway, thanks for your help.